# Bumping version during continuous deployment

Tags: git, github, continuous-integration, travis-ci, continuous-deployment

I'm trying to use Travis to do continuous deployment on an open source project on GitHub. Every merge into `master` gets an automatic version bump and release. The problem is merging the version bump into master *itself* invokes another version bump and release, so I get stuck in a cycle.

How can I set this up so that every change in `master` gets a new automatically bumped version?

Comment: Can you just use the commit ID?  If not, you might have to edit the pre/post commit script to be wise to the direction (and content?) of the merge.  I.e. if the only change is the version file, don't bother with the automerge to release?

Answer (score 0):

You have a few different options:

1. Just use the commit ID as PaulProgrammer suggested in a comment.  You do lose the advantages of [Semantic Versioning](https://semver.org) with this approach though.
2. Use the `TRAVIS_BUILD_NUMBER` or `TRAVIS_JOB_NUMBER` variables in a script that gets executed with Travis CI.  This way you are letting the build server handle your versioning.
3. Use a 3rd party package to handle the versioning (e.g., [MyGet](https://www.myget.org), [Gulp-bump](https://github.com/stevelacy/gulp-bump), [Bumped](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bumped)).

Comment: I don't understand how these help. If I use a package to bump my versions, I still have to commit the changes to `master`, which will kick off the release cycle again.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `[skip ci]` in your second commit to master branch, i.e. commit with message "[skip ci] release v1.0.0" won't start ci again.

Travis docs: https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/customizing-the-build/#skipping-a-build